# Insert call to external PHP script tag into element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, createelement

I am in need of inserting the following into the footer using jQuery. It generates a small ad banner.

```
<script src="http://14489-001.pod1.us01.hst.inclickadserver.com/ads/ads.php?t=MTAwMjsxO2hvcml6b250YWwubGVhZGVyYm9hcmQ=&index=1"></script>
```

I tried the following to no avail:

```
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "http://14489-001.pod1.us01.hst.inclickadserver.com/ads/ads.php?t=MTAwMjsxO2hvcml6b250YWwubGVhZGVyYm9hcmQ=&index=1";
    $(".copyright-container").prepend(s);
```

as well as things like:

```
$("<script src='http://14489-001.pod1.us01.hst.inclickadserver.com/ads/ads.php?t=MTAwMjsxO2hvcml6b250YWwubGVhZGVyYm9hcmQ=&index=1'></scr" + "ipt>").insertBefore('.copyright-container');
```

I'm getting no errors in Chrome's console, but nothing appears. The ad appears if I just paste the script tag into the body of any page on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you load the js, it might not evaluate.  Jquery has a `getScript` function, although using it for cross site js files might be difficult. Here is some sample code.

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: Will this work given that the script being called is PHP and not JS? Also, it self generates a banner. If I use getScript, I'd have to then take action after calling it. The script itself is a banner, so taking further action would depend upon what actions it would accept, though it may not be set up to accept any.

Comment: The response header is `Content-Type:application/javascript; charset=UTF-8` so it's actually js, just with a .php extension probably for some dynamic content in the file.

Comment: Just throw `addElementToBody(iframe_reference); updateIframe(iframe_reference);` into the success callback if it isn't automatically calling it.  If pasting that in works, I'd think getScript would too

Comment: If it has no class or ID, how could I reference the iframe?

Comment: it's a global variable in the javascript file, it's what is called when it loads.  I doubt it's needed but mentioned it because you said you might need to take further action to actually get it to load

Comment: i was just reverse engineering the javascript file so if those functions weren't called, you'd know how to do it.  did you get it to work?

Comment: Going back on my "no" comment - it does load the banner. Only issue I have now is styling it with CSS. Any way I can add a CSS ID using this same getScript?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80326/discussion-between-user1729506-and-rightclick).